# Regex (or not) replace all matches with dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Let's say that I have the following string taken from user input:

```
The @@firstvar@@ went to the @@secondvar@@ with the @@thirdvar@@.
```

Where the values "firstvar" "secondvar" and "thirdvar" all came from user input as well, so they aren't known before runtime.

Is there a way to replace all the matches between sets of "@@" with a corresponding cached variable?

Say for example I have these values cached:

```
cache[firstvar] = "dog"
cache[secondvar] = "river"
cache[thirdvar] = "cat"
```

I want the final output string to be:

```
The dog went to the river with the cat.
```

I've tried regex replace but can't figure it out when the replacements are dynamic like this.

Comment: You could probably use named regex groups. I don't understand how your user input happens though... Are you saying that the user can type out the whole string as "The dog went to the river with the cat." with no knowledge of what that sentence will look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace them by using a function as second argument in [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

```js
const cache = { firstvar: "dog", secondvar: "river", thirdvar: "cat" },
      text = "The @@firstvar@@ went to the @@secondvar@@ with the @@thirdvar@@.",
      regex = /@@(.*?)@@/g;

console.log( text.replace(regex, (_match, group1) => cache[group1]) );
```